# Installing package fails with "tar: Invalid argument"

Tags: debian, apt, docker, debian-wheezy

I'm running a docker container based on `debian:wheezy` to install [wp-mirror](http://www.nongnu.org/wp-mirror/). I'm running into a lot of dependency problems when running `apt-get install wp-mirror`, it seems to work after running that a few times as it's pulling more and more dependencies. Is there a way to avoid / fix that?

Packages I installed before running `apt-get install wp-mirror`:

`apt-get apt-utils aptitude vim gnupg-curl vim`

Currently it's failing with these error messages and I wasn't able to hunt down a solution to that.

```
Get:427 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main xml-core all 0.13+nmu2 [24.2 kB]
Get:428 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main xterm amd64 278-4 [613 kB]
Fetched 1254 MB in 2min 14s (9294 kB/s)
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76, <> line 428.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Configuring mysql-server-5.5
----------------------------

While not mandatory, it is highly recommended that you set a password for the MySQL administrative "root" user.

If this field is left blank, the password will not be changed.

New password for the MySQL "root" user:



Repeat password for the MySQL "root" user:


tar: ./shlibs: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./symbols: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./postinst: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./postrm: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./control: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./md5sums: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: .: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libkmod2_9-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
tar: ./postrm: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./symbols: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./shlibs: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./md5sums: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./postinst: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: ./control: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: .: Cannot change ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Invalid argument
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libpipeline1_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
```

I'm talking about these `tar` errors that keep showing up for a lot of dependencies.

Any idea what's going on there? Thank you!

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: I don't have one yet, I'm just getting started with Docker so right now it's just the base debian image with me attaching to it with `docker run -i -t ... /bin/bash`. I know that's not the ideal use case.